# How to remove imported modules from code coverage in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, code-coverage, istanbul, karma-coverage

In my module.ts file, I have imported my own library 'ImportFileFeedModule' as below

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,MatDialogModule,ImportFileFeedModule,MatIconModule],
  declarations: [DialogFileComponent]
})
```

while running coverage report files in the imported modules also showed in coverage reports.

my karma config is as below

```js
  config.set({
    ...baseConfig,
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      ...baseConfig.coverageIstanbulReporter,
      dir: join(__dirname, '../../../coverage/libs/widget/dialog-file-import')
    },
    htmlReporter: {
      ...baseConfig.htmlReporter,
      outputDir: 'karma_html/libs/widget/dialog-file-import', // where to put the reports 
      reportName: 'report-summary-filename', // report summary filename; browser info by default
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want coverage to be run on the imported files?

Comment: i have wrote coverage for that library separately. i want to show coverage for this particular module only